# PHP: [Bug] Why does "display_errors" exist if only "error_reporting" can hide or show errors?

Tags: php, error-reporting, ini-set

> EDIT: My Environment is the following (this is relevant to the
>   answer):
>
> - Microsoft IIS 10.0 Express
> - Windows 7 Professional SP1
> - PHP Version 5.6.16 x86 FastCGI

I am trying to figure out what purpose the setting "display_errors" has.
In the following code, I am attempting to *hide the PHP Notice* that is thrown at line 9. Naturally one would think that simply setting

```
 display_errors = 'Off'
```

would accomplish this, but it seems to have no effect.

I am of the understanding that "error_reporting" lets you choose *which* errors are caught, and "display_errors" determines whether or not the error messages are echoed to the user. Am I mistaken? In most of my Google searches, I see people setting *both*

```
error_reporting = 0
```

and

```
display_errors = 'Off'
```

But, why even bother with

```
   display_errors = 'Off'
```

when it does not have an effect anyway?

My test code:

```
<?php
//ini_set("error_reporting", 0);
ini_set("display_errors", "Off");
ini_set("display_startup_errors", "Off");
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");

echo "Hey<br />";

echo $myarr["hey"];
```

When I run this code, I see the following error message (this is a link to the image, since I don't have enough reputation to post it here):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB6Au.png

PHP: The error message generated for line 9 should be hidden from the user. Why does "display_errors" exist if it does nothing?

Comment: error_reporting is a function not a varible. error_reporting(0); should turn all errors off. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @JasonK error_reporting can be modified using ini_set. It's in the "Examples" section on the PHP manual page you linked

Comment: **Why you fixed those without hidden it !!**

Comment: Fix those errors. So you no need to hide those. Its best

Comment: @Abdulla I intentionally put the error in the code I posted so that I could better understand PHP error-handling mechanism. Also, the point of it is to hide *unknown* errors from users that you, the developer, have not caught yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trial and error and using ShiraNai7's explanations I have found that this is a bug in PHP on Microsoft IIS and FastCGI. See link to bug:

**Bug #44729    display_errors = Off not respected**

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44729

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP errors and their configuration may seem <del>a bit</del> really weird if one isn't familiar with the inner workings. There is a lot going on.

### [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

- controls whether PHP's default error handler prints errors to the output as they happen

  - error codes suppresed by `error_reporting` will not printed
- controls whether PHP's default exception handler prints uncaught exceptions to the output

### [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors)

- controls whether PHP's default error handler logs errors to [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)

  - error codes suppresed by `error_reporting` will not be logged
- controls whether PHP's default exception handler logs exceptions to [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)

### [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

- defines a global mask for errors that should be reported
- this option is used by the PHP's default error handler (see above)
- this option should be used by the [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) too

### [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

- defines a custom error handler
- it is always called if an error occurs (even if its suppressed)
- if it returns `false`, the PHP's default error handler WILL be called (and print / log errors according to the settings)
- if it returns `null` or `true` or throws an exception, the PHP's default error handler WILL NOT be called (and thus it won't print / log anything).

### [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

- defines a custom exception handler
- PHP's default exception handler will not be called if a custom handler is defined (and thus it won't print / log anything)

---

> But, why even bother with "display_errors = 'Off'" when it does not have an effect anyway?

There are combinations of the above settings that make `display_errors` not useless.

Examples:

- `display_errors` **must** be `off` in *php.ini* on production servers to prevent leaking of possibly sensitive data

  - an error / exception can happen before you have the chance to change any of the other settings
- if you want to log errors but not print them to the output, you set `display_errors` to `off` and `log_errors` to `on`
- if you are using a custom error handler that prints custom error messages but you also want to use `error_log`, you set `display_errors` to `off`

Comment: Sorry for my slowness...I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. Could you show me a short example (in code) where "display_errors = Off" would have an effect on the error output?

Comment: Iirc `display_errors` outputs the error directly as part of the output, if the type isn't suppressed. Thus one should set it to Off in production.

Comment: @user3163495 I added more info to the answer and provided example cases where `display_errors` has an effect.

Comment: @ShiraNai7 have you tried testing the code that I posted? My example contradicts your statement "if you want to log errors but not print them to the output, you set display_errors to off"

Comment: @user3163495 I did and it doesn't show any errors. Are you by any chance using a custom error handler? The error message you are getting doesn't look like it was produced by PHP.

Comment: @ShiraNai7 I have not set up a custom error handler. Where would I check if one existed, if it's not in the code? Can they exist in php.ini?

Comment: @user3163495 Try calling `var_dump(set_error_handler('var_dump'));` and see what it returns. It should return `NULL` if there was no custom error handler.

Comment: @ShiraNai7 I replaced line 9 with "var_dump(set_error_handler('var_dump'));" It returned NULL. See image: http://i.imgur.com/tOz9TTQ.png

Comment: @user3163495 Tried it through a browser (PHP 5.6) and through console (PHP 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 & 7.0) - it just outputs "Hey". See https://3v4l.org/NYsRA (though it looks like HHVM doesn't support this setting).

Comment: @ShiraNai7 Thanks for the analysis. Do you think it has something to do with me using Microsoft IIS and fast CGI?

Comment: @ShiraNai7 This turned out to be a bug ShiraNai7